# problem with dns

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm currently experiencing a issue with my dns, affecting 'host' and 'apt-get'. The contents of my `/etc/network/interfaces`;

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.75.76

cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.75.76

cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
namerserver 75.75.75.75

cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original
nameserver 75.75.75.75
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of dig host. replace host with the mirror in question.

Comment: dig us.archive.ubuntu.com 
connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Ive also edtied  /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

no luck.

Comment: i guess you should try other dns server such as 8.8.8.8

Comment: This server is also inside a virtualbox guest host. This might be worth mentioning.

Comment: sounds like you need to fix 75.75.75.75 check routes, and your not firewalled etc.

Comment: what is the output of "ifconfig eth0" and "route -n" ?

Comment: I.e., do you have network connectivity apart from DNS?

Answer (score 0):

1: Remove the line

```
nameserver 75.75.75.75
```

from /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base. It isn't needed, since the same information is included on the `dns-nameservers` line in the eth0 stanza in /etc/network/interfaces.

2: Make sure that the server at 75.75.75.75 is in fact a DNS name server. If it doesn't, insert the correct IP addresses on the `dns-nameservers` line in the eth0 stanza in /etc/network/interfaces.

3: Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

to recreate the symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf` -> `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` since it appears that the symlink is not present.

4: Run

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

to cause `resolv.conf` to be regenerated using the latest information on the `dns-nameservers` line.